# baposter.cls - problems with \usetikzlibrary{snakes}

Tags: errors, baposter, tikzlibrary

I would like to create a poster using baposter.cls. I downloaded the example one finds at https://www.latextemplates.com/template/baposter-portrait-poster.
Using pdflatex to compile the example I get the following error:

> /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarysnakes.code.tex:14:
>   Snakes have been superseded by decorations. Please use thedecoration
>   libraries instead of the snakes library on input line 14.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Since the `baposter` class isn't really actively maintained, AFAIK, you really have two options: change your local version of the class or use a different poster class. If you are not using the `coils` or `triangles` border options in your poster (and who would? :) ) then it suffices to delete line line 159 of the class which loads the `snakes` library.  But if you want to use them, you should replace that line with the following:

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.shapes}
```

Then to use the  `coils` or `triangles` borders, then you need to change the following commands:

```
\newcommand{\baposter@box@drawborder@coils}[1]{
  \draw[color=#1,segment amplitude=0.35em,segment length=0.4em,snake=coil] \baposterBoxGetShape;%
}
\newcommand{\baposter@box@drawborder@triangles}[1]{
  \draw[color=#1,segment amplitude=0.2em,segment length=0.4em,snake=triangles] \baposterBoxGetShape;%
}
```

to

```
\newcommand{\baposter@box@drawborder@coils}[1]{
  \draw[color=#1,decorate,decoration={coil,amplitude=0.35em,segment length=0.4em,}] \baposterBoxGetShape;%
}
\newcommand{\baposter@box@drawborder@triangles}[1]{
  \draw[color=#1,decorate,decoration={triangles,segment length=0.4em,shape height=.4em,shape width=.2em}] \baposterBoxGetShape;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This problem is overcome. Since the LaTex ouput is still strange I decided to use another poster class...

Comment: @J.Baetge You're welcome. In the long term that might be the best solution. But the `baposteer` class is quite simple to use, so if you're in a hurry, it's still a good choice. (I use it for my own posters.)